# AMD RX 570 GPU slower rendering than NVidia GTX 1050 Ti?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, performance

I recently built a new PC running on a Ryzen 7 2700X CPU and AMD Radeon RX 570 GPU. However, I'm getting significantly longer Cycles rendering times than my old Intel i5 PC running on an older NVidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti model graphics card. Am I doing something wrong, or what exactly is going on here? GPU is selected in Blender Preferences and all drivers are up to date.

Comment: CUDA has been far more optimized for a while than other rendering pipelines so this could be your issue. Only NVIDIA cards can run the CUDA rendering pipeline. Also check your "Cycles render device" in the "System" tab of preferences. You may need to use a different render device. I hear that AMD cards work great with the RADEON PRO RENDERER for blender (Developed and mantained by AMD) and are faster with that than the native cycles engine atm.

Comment: Thank you! I vaguely heard something about Radeon ProRender but had no clue they they had a Blender plug-in. Will give that a try and see how it goes. :)

Comment: OMG, this worked! Installed both the ProRender and the material library they have developed for it and it works like a charm and it renders A LOT faster than Cycles. Thanks so much man!!!